What is the name for this sort of relationship between vector spaces and linear maps?
I am following the development of linear algebra in Axler's popular "Linear Algebra Done Right." The author formalizes the relationship between two vector spaces (along with the linear maps between them) and the spaces of matrices over the underlying field. To understand this, I am summarizing the major results and drawing some commutative diagrams. Below are my brief notes on the development in this book. Question: is there a term that denotes the relationship in the final diagram below?
Quick Summary
Define our spaces
Let $V,W$ be vector spaces (over $\mathbb{F}$) of finite dimensions $n,m$, respectively.

Define $L\left(V,W\right)$ as the vector space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$.

In the following, let $T \in L\left(V,W\right)$, arbitrary.




Define isomorphisms

Two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic iff they have the same dimension.

Hence, we know that $V \cong \mathbb{F}^n$ and $W\cong \mathbb{F}^m$.
Note that we have not constructed such isomorphisms (yet).




Define the vector space of matrices
Now we introduce the vector space of matrices:

The set of $m\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space under element-wise addition and scalar multiplication, denoted $\mathbb{F}^{m,n}$.

We also define matrix multiplication such that an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ can be thought of as a linear mapping $A: \mathbb{F}^{n,1} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m,1}$.



Map linear maps to matrices
Now we can relate linear mapping between $V$ and $W$ with matrices:

Big result: Given bases for $V$ and $W$, we can construct an isomorphism  $M: L\left(V,W\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m,n}$. Hence, $L\left(V,W\right) \cong \mathbb{F}^{m,n}$.

That is, $M$ associates a matrix with any linear map from $V$ to $W$.


The matrix operations that we defined above ensure that the vector space operations of $L\left(V,W\right)$ are preserved by this isomorphism: \begin{align*} M\left(S+T\right) & = M\left(S\right) + M\left(T\right) \\ M\left(\lambda S\right) & = \lambda M\left(S\right) \\ M\left(ST\right) & = M\left(S\right)M\left(T\right)\end{align*}

How do matrices "map"?
So far, we know that $L\left(V,W\right)$ is a vector space (of linear maps) which is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb{F}^{m,n}$. We still need to "move over" the vectors from $V$ and $W$ to $\mathbb{F}^{n,1}$ and $\mathbb{F}^{m,1}$.

When we defined matrix multiplication, we noted that multiplying by an $m \times n$ matrix is a linear map from $\mathbb{F}^{n,1}$ to $\mathbb{F}^{m,1}$.
Define the isomorphisms $M_V: V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{n,1}$ and $M_W: W \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m,1}$ which map vectors in $V$ and $W$ to matrices ("vectors") of their coordinates in the respective bases.

We will suppress the subscripts to express the relationship between the mappings $M$ discussed so far.



Putting it all together

Big result: Linear maps act like matrix multiplication: $$ M\left(Tv\right) = M\left(T\right)M\left(v\right). $$

That is, first applying $Tv$ and then mapping $Tv$ to a matrix is equivalent to mapping $T$ and $v$ to matrices and then performing matrix multiplication.
This last equation is depicted in the following commutative diagram.




Question
It feels like we have some sort of "isomorphism" between the tuples $\left(V,W,L\left(V,W\right)\right)$ and $\left(\mathbb{F}^{n,1}, \mathbb{F}^{m,1}, \mathbb{F}^{m,n}\right)$ which I have written as $M$ such that $$ M\left(v, w, T\right) = \left(M\left(v\right), M\left(w\right), M\left(T\right)\right)$$ where $$ w = Tv \iff M\left(w\right) = M\left(T\right)M\left(v\right).$$ Is there a term to express this?

Are you familiar with categories? I would describe the phenomenon you are obseving by saying that you have constructed an equivalence from the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces with chosen basis to the category of matrices.

This is a kind of functoriality. You've actually left out one more important aspect of this equivalence, which is that if $U, V, W$ are three vector spaces and we equip them with bases, and $T : U \to V, S : V \to W$ are two linear maps, then matrix multiplication corresponds to composition of linear maps. This is the sort of thing that a functor does, convert one kind of composition to another kind.
As Thorgott says in the comments, one way to make this precise is to consider a category $\text{Base}$ of what we might call "based vector spaces," whose

objects are pairs $(V, B)$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a given field $F$ together with a basis $B$ of $V$, and whose
morphisms $T : (V, B) \to (W, C)$ are linear maps $V \to W$.

Then we consider a second category $\text{Mat}$, what we might call the "category of matrices," whose

objects are non-negative integers $n$ (thought of as the vector spaces $F^n$), and whose
morphisms $n \to m$ are $m \times n$ matrices, with composition given by matrix multiplication.

Now the claim is that there is a functor $M : \text{Base} \to \text{Mat}$ which sends an object $(V, B)$ to $\dim V$ (really, to $F^{\dim V}$) and which sends a linear map $T : (V, B) \to (W, C)$ to the matrix of $T$ with respect to the bases $B, C$. Moreover both of these categories are "$F$-linear," meaning that their homsets are $F$-vector spaces and composition is bilinear, and $M$ is an $F$-linear functor, meaning it respects this $F$-vector space structure.
This description does not appear to directly reproduce the correspondence between elements of $V$ and elements of $F^{\dim V}$, but this correspondence appears if you consider the special object $(F, \{ 1 \})$; maps from this object to $(V, B)$ are in natural bijection with elements of $V$, and on writing these maps with respect to these two bases we get elements of $V$ written in the basis $B$.
One final claim about this functor is that it's an equivalence of categories; this  means the functor $M$ has an inverse. This inverse, of course, sends a positive integer $n$ to the vector space $F^n$ and sends an $m \times n$ matrix to the corresponding linear map $F^n \to F^m$. So this makes precise the sense in which $M$ is an "isomorphism."

 Confusingly there's a third category you might have wanted to write down here, which is just the category $\text{FinVect}$ of finite-dimensional vector spaces, where we haven't chosen a basis. This category is also equivalent to the other two categories above, but this is actually much more confusing; there's an obvious functor $\text{Mat} \to \text{FinVect}$ but no longer an obvious functor $\text{FinVect} \to \text{Mat}$. To write down such a functor requires arbitrarily choosing, for every finite-dimensional vector space, a basis of it, which you might consider strangely inelegant. Personally I've never quite known what to make of this.


Minor nit: functors with inverses are isomorphisms, not equivalences, as you know. You mean a functor $N$ such that $NM(V)$ is isomorphic to $V$, and $MN(n)$ is isomorphic (in this case equal to) $n$.

@Arturo: the correct notion of inverse for functors is exactly a functor $G$ satisfying the definition of an equivalence of categories; I didn't want to get into this because this is already too much category theory for a linear algebra student who's presumably never seen any category theory before.

It's fair enough that you don't want to get too much into that, but I would disagree with "correct notion of inverse"; if you look at $\mathsf{Cat}$, then there is a clear notion of "inverse of a functor", which matches that of any category, and would require $GF=\mathrm{Id}{\mathsf{C}}$ and $FG=\mathrm{Id}{\mathsf{D}}$, not $GF\cong\mathrm{Id}_{\mathsf{C}}$, etc.. I agree, though, that the "right notion" of "these categories should be considered the same/isomorphic" is "equivalence of categories", not "isomorphism of categories", which presumably is what you are getting at

@QiaochuYuan Thanks for the extensive answer! I've informally known for a while there that was this relationship between linear maps and matrices, but it's surprising to hear that all of this category-theoretical machinery is required to make that precise. Always wondered why no one "named" this relationship in linear algebra courses.

@stuz: there is not really any machinery here, this is all just terminology and it can be fully unwound into a series of more concrete elementary statements. The point of the terminology is to compress all of those statements into a single useful reusable higher-level concept, which is the point of all terminology.
